# First order stochastic ordering implies countably additive probability measure?

Tags: probability, references, measure-theory, stochastic-ordering

Let $P$ be a [finitely additive probability measure](https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-0-387-21659-1_5). I learn from my friend that:

$[P(X>Y)=1 \implies \mathbb E_P[X]>\mathbb E_P[Y]]\iff$ $P$ is countably additive.

Seems to be a very useful result. Is this result covered in textbooks or literatures?

Comment: Where did you learn this result from, dodo? Citation, if possible, is always appreciated.

Comment: It's a little strange to say "*finitely additive probability measure*" because a probability measure by definition is automatically countably additive.

Comment: @User1865345 From my friend.

Comment: @Zhanxiong Definition given in link.

Comment: @dodo "From my friend" is not the "citation" we would like to see.  I guess what User1865345 asked is from which publication your friend found this result -- could you share the source with us (is it from the linked book you added? If yes, can be be more specific by listing the exercise number?)?

Comment: @Zhanxiong He claims that he find it by himself. That is why I am also looking for a reference (i.e. textbook) about this.